# Cannot find module for NodeJS app inside Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a NodeJS app using some modules that I'm trying to put inside docker image.

```
    const Xvfb = require('xvfb')
    const fs = require("fs")
    const { exec } = require("child_process")

    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000

    console.log('hello world');
```

I'm not sure about the paths to user but here are the steps I followed :

My app is in folder : **/mynodejs** and all the following commands are run from this folder :

1. I Created the file package.json with content

   ```
   {
     "name": "appname",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "Node.js on Docker",
     "author": "Some Name",
     "main": "app.js",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "node app.js"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "express": "^4.16.1"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Created the file Dockerfile

   ```
   nano Dockerfile
   ```

With content :

```
    FROM node:14            
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .    
    CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

3. Created the file : **.dockerignore**

   ```
   node_modules
   ```
4. Built the file :

   ```
   sudo docker build -t myapp .
   ```
5. Check if the image was created. It's created.

   ```
   sudo docker images
   ```
6. Test the docker image

   ```
   docker run myapp
   ```

Error :

```
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
      throw err;
      ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'xvfb'
    Require stack:
    - /usr/src/app/app.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:11:22)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/app.js' ]
```

The error is not specific to the module 'xhr2' shown here. The error is raised at the first call of **require('something')**

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Comment: You tag your image as `myapp` when you build it, but you run `streamer`. Typo?

Comment: @HansKilian yes. It's just a typo when writing the question on SO.

Comment: I tried reproducing it. My app.js was the code from here https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html. It works as it should for me. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Hans Kilian. Indeed the example you provided works properly. However if you just add `const { launch, getStream }  = require("puppeteer-stream")` at the begining of the same code, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @HansKilian I added the application. Do you have any idea please ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing xvfb as a dependency in your package.json file. Add it, so your package.json file becomes

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "Some Name",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "xvfb": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

I can see that there are different versions of the xvfb package on Npm, so maybe you want "@cypress/xvfb" version 1.2.4 instead. The cypress one is older but has a lot more weekly downloads. I'm not familiar with xvfb.

If you have npm installed on your host, you can add the package to the package.json file using the command

```
npm install xvfb
```

or

```
npm install @cypress/xvfb
```

rather than editing the package.json file by hand